# NEXT JS: Redirec to external URL on Click of button (and not on loading a route)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have been continiously trying to redirect to an external URL with absolute path using NEXTJS in order to perform oAuth verification.

I tried using

`<button><a href='absolute_path'>Redirect to Website</a></button>`

`onClick = () => window.location.href = 'absolute_path'`

`onClick = () => window.location.assign('absolute_path')`

`onClick = () => router.push('absolute_path')`

`onClick = () => router.replace('absolute_path')`

But all of these always append the result at the end:

localhost:3000/absolute_path

I saw:

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: 'https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2',
        permanent: false,
        basePath: false,
      },
    ];
  },
```

But this performs immediate redirect on page load, I don't want that instead I want to redirect to external URL based on a button click so that I could inject URL params on the Go.

One way could be to modify URL parameters on button click and then writing an expression in the above `config` so that it matches and redirects, however that seems to be super complicated so I wanted to know if there's any better solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using an absolute URL on the `onClick` callbacks? The following should work just fine: `onClick={() => router.push('https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2')}`

Comment: The one that you mentioned redirects me here: `http://localhost:3000/https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2` and not `https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2`

Router.push would navigate you to any path after `/` however I expected router.replace to replace everything but that doesn't work as well